# how to get around newlines with jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

When parsing json using jQuery.parseJSON(), I get this error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal
```

A quick search revelead that this is caused by newlines in the json string.

I get my json string from PHP using json_encode().

Is there a way to encode it in such a way that jQuery.parseJSON() would not complain and still retain the newline information?

Comment: Never had this issue before....strange, because json doesn't really care about whitespace.

Comment: You can use Javascript's inbuilt [JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: Can you post the PHP array and the result from parseJSON?

Comment: Unless of course you're leaving a string unterminated when you end the line. That is invalid JSON, and if you're using PHP to create the json that shouldn't happen

Comment: Are you able to post the actual JSON itself? You can use `console.log(yourJson)` before you parse it and than post the result. Would be much easier to analyse a possible solution.

Comment: My json has some data that needs newline i.e. ..., "greetings": "Hi there!\n How are you?",...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the v8 bug tracker (http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=616), this is actually the correct behavior:

"Newlines are not allowed inside JSON strings (no control characters are, see, e.g., 
JsonStringCharacter production of ECMA262 5ed, section 15.2.1.1)."

So it depends really on what you want to do - in this instance, as you need the newlines, you need to escape them before doing the json parse:

```
//myjsonobject contains the json object

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(myjsonobject.replace(/\n/g,"\\n"));
```